# Message about sent is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, email, post

I have code that checks whether the address is ok and sends it. After sending the information appears that the message was sent.

When I give the wrong email address format - appears the message.

Then when I give the correct address - the message you sent is not working.

What is wrong?

jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    {literal}
    function validateEmail(email) {
        return /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/.test(email);
    }
    {/literal}


    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#mybtn').click(function() {
            var sEmail = $('#email').val();
            if ($.trim(sEmail).length == 0) {
                alert('Please input your email');
               //e.preventDefault();
            }
            if (validateEmail(sEmail)) {
                $('#contact').submit(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : '/contact/process',
                        data : $('#contact').serialize(),
                        type: "POST",
                        success : function(){
                            $('form').find('#name, #email, #message').val('');
                            $('#messageAfterSend').addClass('alert alert-success').text("Thank you for send email").slideUp(3200);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }); 
            }
            else {
                $('#messageAfterSend').addClass('alert alert-success').text("Invalid email.").slideUp(3200);
                $('form').find('#email').val('');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @Barmar No errors in console.

Comment: It's almost always wrong to bind one event handler inside another event handler. Your `.submit()` handler won't be used until the second time the user clicks on the submit button, because you're not binding it until after the first click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function validateEmail(email) {
    return /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/.test(email);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#contact').on('submit', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
           url : '/contact/process',
           data : $(this).serialize(),
           type: "POST",
           success : function(){
               $('form').find('#name, #email, #message').val('');
               $('#messageAfterSend').addClass('alert alert-success').text("Thank you for send email").slideUp(3200);
           }
       });
   });
   $('#mybtn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var sEmail = $('#email').val();
        if ($.trim(sEmail).length == 0) {
            alert('Please input your email');
        }
        if (validateEmail(sEmail)) {
             $('#contact').trigger('submit');
        } else {
            $('#messageAfterSend').addClass('alert alert-success').text("Invalid email.").slideUp(3200);
            $('form').find('#email').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Try this way, first set listener on your contact form, second listen for event on "send button"
If it's "simple form" you could just put everything in on('submit') listener

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uz3mLm9n/%20Fiddle)**